# Java Eclipselink on TomEE gives "Missing required persistence.xml"

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to setup Eclipselink on TomEE but i ran into the problem that i get an error about missing the persistence.xml. But the persistence.xml is present at ProjectPath/META-INF/persistence.xml.

I'm running a Maven project on IntelliJ with Jersey and Eclipselink. This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="DietMakerPostgres">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>database.DietEntity</class>
    <class>database.DietSavedEntity</class>
    <class>database.DietSentenceEntity</class>
    <class>database.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxxx:5432/dietmaker"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my restful webservice:

```
@Path("/api")
@Stateless
public class DietService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "DietMakerPostgres")
    private EntityManager em;
    // The Java method will process HTTP GET requests
    @GET
    // The Java method will produce content identified by the MIME Media type "text/plain"
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getClichedMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }


}
```

The stacktrace:

```
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder init
INFO: -------------------------
TomcatWebAppBuilder.init 
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory configureApplication
INFO: Configuring enterprise application: C:\Users\Maikel\IdeaProjects\DieetMakerPro\out\artifacts\DieetMakerPro_war_exploded
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.InitEjbDeployments deploy
INFO: Auto-deploying ejb DietService: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=DietService)
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.OutputGeneratedDescriptors writeEjbJar
INFO: Dumping Generated ejb-jar.xml to: D:\Developer Tools\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.1\temp\ejb-jar-1529900398401626568.xml
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.OutputGeneratedDescriptors writeOpenejbJar
INFO: Dumping Generated openejb-jar.xml to: D:\Developer Tools\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.1\temp\openejb-jar-8207889764066155084.xml
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
SEVERE: FAIL ... DietService:   Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "em" to unit "DietMakerPostgres"
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
SEVERE: Invalid EjbModule(name=, path=C:\Users\Maikel\IdeaProjects\DieetMakerPro\out\artifacts\DieetMakerPro_war_exploded)
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
SEVERE: FAIL ... :  Missing required persistence.xml for @PersistenceContext ref "em" to unit "DietMakerPostgres"
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
SEVERE: Invalid WebModule(name=, path=C:\Users\Maikel\IdeaProjects\DieetMakerPro\out\artifacts\DieetMakerPro_war_exploded)
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults deploy
INFO: Set the 'openejb.validation.output.level' system property to VERBOSE for increased validation details.
feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]
org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=DieetMakerPro_war_exploded)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:82)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:293)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:830)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:974)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1167)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1148)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:986)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=DieetMakerPro_war_exploded)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:989)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:901)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=DieetMakerPro_war_exploded)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.deploy(ReportValidationResults.java:82)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AppInfoBuilder.build(AppInfoBuilder.java:293)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:830)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:974)
    ... 46 more

feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

feb 12, 2013 9:08:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:309)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1419)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said you are running a maven project.

By default maven will not pack that odd path into your application.

Place the persistence.xml into: `ProjectPath/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

Comment: Ok, i didn't knew that. Thanks! But i'm still getting "An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted". Im guessing i mixed something up with the JPA?

Comment: Solved my problem, i mixed the JPA up. I needed to use org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl as provider instead of an non-existing provider generated by IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. One fine day the generated war file was missing persistence.xml. And it was working before.
Getting older version of project also did not help.

It seems that something got corrupted in local maven repository. So I deleted repository folder under .m2 folder, and rebuild the project (using mvn install). The tool downloaded all the required repository again and the problem was resolved.

Hope it helps someone facing similar situation.